# HTML Facebook App Link

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, hyperlink

I am currently developing a website for a friend and I wanted to include a Facebook link to his fanpage.

This is my function that opens either the browser page or the app (if user is signed in with FB App installed).

```js
<script>
        function oL(){
        setTimeout(function () { window.location = "https://www.facebook.com/{PageName}"; },10000);
        window.location = "fb://page/{PageID}/";
        }
</script>
```

For some reason, this is only working properly for Android devices such as my Nexus 4 and my Tablet. My iPhone 6s just opens the Facebook app but not the specific Fanpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, solved it. iOS and Android want different links.

iOS: fb://page?id={yourID}
Android: fb://page/{yourID}/